# Vercel Next js Uncaught (in promise) ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 0 failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

After deleting node modules and package-lock.json, I am getting the above error, when I reload any page.
When I restart the project it works fine for the first time. But again when i reload the page, showing a blank page and giving the above error in the console.

[image]

**next.config.js**

```
    const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass')
    const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css');
    const withFonts = require('next-fonts');
    const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
    const optimizedImages = require('next-optimized-images');

    module.exports = withPlugins([
        [optimizedImages, {
            inlineImageLimit: 8192,
            imagesFolder: 'images',
            imagesName: '[name]-[hash].[ext]',
            handleImages: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'svg', 'webp', 'gif', 'ico'],
            optimizeImages: true,
            optimizeImagesInDev: false,
            mozjpeg: {
                quality: 80,
            },
            optipng: {
                optimizationLevel: 3,
            },
            pngquant: false,
            gifsicle: {
                interlaced: true,
                optimizationLevel: 3,
            },
            webp: {
                preset: 'default',
                quality: 75,
            },
        }],
        [withCSS],[withFonts],[withSass]
    ]);
```

Comment: Can you provide more context? Or if it is public, share the Github link?

Comment: This is not public, what files exactly you need, I can post their code.

Comment: Could be webpack-related, mind posting your `next.config.json`, please?

Comment: Also, might be worth deleting your `.next` folder and running the app again.

Comment: I try it to remove `.next` but still not working

Answer (score 38):

Try removing the `.next` directory. That is what worked for me :)

Comment: I always forget to try this prior to Googling. So thank you for your answer and helping me quickly fix this strange error.